# Encoding german characters

Tags: oracle, perl, encoding, character-encoding

I need to import with `load data` some perl - generated files to oracle database.
Perl-script get a webpage and write csv file.

Here a simplified script:

```
use File::Slurp;     
my $c= ( $user && $passwd )
        ? get("$protocol://$user:$passwd\@$url")
        : get("$protocol://$url");

    write_file("$VZ_GET/$FileTS.$typ.csv",$c);
```

Here a sample line from the webpage:

```
5052;97;Jan;Ihrfelt 5053;97;Jari;Honko 5121;97;Katja;Keitaanniemi 5302;97;Ola;Södermark 5421;97;Sven;Sköld 5609;97;Peter;Näslund
```

Content of the webpage is saved in var $c.

Here a sample line of csv file:

```
5053;97;Jari;Honko
```

Here a load command:

```
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE LIQA
TRUNCATE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
(
    LIQA_ANALYST_ID,
    LIQA_FIRM_ID,
    LIQA_ANALYST_FIRST_NAME,
    LIQA_ANALYST_LAST_NAME,
    LIQA_TS_INSERT  DATE 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'
)
```

Command `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` returns `AL32UTF8`.

The generated csv file is recognized as  `UTF-8 Unicode text`.

Anyhow I cant import german characters. In the csv file they are still correct. But it is not the case in the database.

I have also tried to convert $c like this:

```
$c = encode("iso-8859-1", $c);
```

The generated csv file is stll recognized as  `UTF-8 Unicode text`.

I have no clue how can I fix it.

Comment: Hi MaMu. Could you rather share a cohesive code snippet from the current version of your script? That would help explain the problem in more detail and would help solving it!

Comment: Honko and Keitaanniemi are Finnish, the others are Swedish. (Well, the first could be German.)

Comment: @tripleee: oh, ok. indeed. but i just want to import umlauts. like öäü.

Comment: Actually, they are not strictly linguistically speaking umlauts in Finnish or Swedish, either (^:

Comment: @thunk: i have edited my question. anyhow i think, that the problem is more the load data. cause the files seems to be correct...

Comment: @tripleee: feel free to correct me...

Comment: Could you show your `write_file` sub please?

Comment: @simbabque: I'm just using  File::Slurp.

Comment: To go about this from a different angle... have you tried `INSERT`ing the records directly with DBI?

Comment: no, i 'd love to use load data.

Comment: What do the characters end up looking like? Raw bytes in hex would hopefully be revealing. For example, ä should be `0xC3 0xA4`. (As an aside, Unicode calls this character LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS which is more correct than the implied "umlaut" e.g. in the HTML character entity name `&auml;`.)

Comment: yes, i have checked the line "ter;N..slund.561" and hex is showing:  7465 723b 4ec3 a473 6c75 6e64 0a35 3631. So ä is  c3 a4 (as you have mentioned).

Comment: Then the output is correct UTF-8, so I assume this is in the CSV file. The incorrect bytes are what we need to see.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not getting you... You mean the incorrect bytes in db (stricly speaking in the table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it:

```
$c = decode( 'utf-8', $c );
$c = encode( 'iso-8859-1' , $c );
```